# Hide Layout/View on ListView scroll up

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

[image]

Excuse my terrible paint skills, but that's a picture of my proposed layout.

I would like the blue part to be a RelativeLayout. Underneath the blue RelativeLayout is a ViewPager with Tabs, each tab containing a ListView.

What I'd like to do is be able to hide the blue layout as the user scrolls down the ListView, and reappear as the user scrolls up to the top of the ListView.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which Library you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this library [ParallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)

It very easy to implement and it supports both scrollviews, listviews wtc

I use the following to browse for new libraries etc..enjoy :D

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

I guess a follow-up question...where can I search for libraries to use such as this one?

Comment: @jaytj95 check [this](http://www.andevcon.com/news/46-android-developer-libraries-by-category) out for awesome libraries.

Comment: bookmarked thanks :D ...still download the android app since you can try examples on device and set your favourites

Comment: your link sir has some pretty cool libraries...libraries make this planet such a nicer place :)

Comment: This library works well, but how can I add the ViewPager's Tab strip in between the blue layout and the listview?

Comment: Hi ! myself I would parallax scrollview , instead of the red listview I use a tablelayout. for the scrollview is important to set in the xml app:parallax_views_num="3" . What do you think?

Comment: wait sorry forget about the previous comment to set 3 views...stick with 2 views but im afraid you have to still use a tablelayout and parallax scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lockable scroll view by this you can put your whole layout into it and lock the scroll at the specific location points on the screen